# Age streamed HTTP decryption in Rust

Tags: http, rust, encryption

I want to implement a rust program which downloads an age encrypted file from a webserver using http range headers (chunk by chunk) and decrypts it with the age decryptor before writing the chunk into the output file on the disk.

main.rs

```
let object_key = "image2.jpeg.age";
    let file_size = 10177424;
    let chunk_size = 1024 * 1024;
    let private_key = "AGE-SECRET-KEY-16QJNAR8ZNXVZG486G0KH3XELY66PXWQY7040099ZWZ2R3K9793TS93QC95";

    let identity = Identity::from_str(&private_key).unwrap();

    let mut output_file = File::create("/Users/adamsmith/Downloads/".to_owned() + object_key.replace(".age", "").as_str())?;

    let mut http_reader = HttpReader::new(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/download/range",
        object_key,
        file_size,
        chunk_size
    );

    let mut buffer = vec![0; chunk_size];
    
    // Initialize the age decryptor
    let decryptor = match age::Decryptor::new_buffered(BufReader::new(&mut http_reader)).unwrap() {
        age::Decryptor::Recipients(d) => d,
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };
    let mut reader = decryptor.decrypt(iter::once(&identity as &dyn age::Identity)).unwrap();
    println!("Reader initialized first chunk readed!");

    let readed_bytes = reader.read_to_end(&mut buffer);
    println!("{:?}", readed_bytes);

    // while true {
    //     let bytes_read = reader.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    //     println!("Readed bytes: {:?}", bytes_read);

    //     // Exit if the bytes_read smaller than the chunk size.
    //     // It means that was the last part.
    //     if (bytes_read < chunk_size) {
    //         break;
    //     }
    // }
```

I also created a struct which implements the io::Read trait to get the file using HTTP requests.

```
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use reqwest;
use tokio::task;

pub struct HttpReader {
    url: String,
    object_key: String,
    file_size: usize,
    chunk_size: usize,
    start_byte: usize,
}

impl HttpReader {
    pub fn new(url: &str, object_key: &str, file_size: usize, chunk_size: usize) -> Self {
        HttpReader {
            url: url.to_string(),
            object_key: object_key.to_string(),
            file_size: file_size,
            chunk_size: chunk_size,
            start_byte: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl Read for HttpReader {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        task::block_in_place(|| {

            // Calculate the end byte regarding to the filesize
            let mut end_byte = self.start_byte + self.chunk_size - 1;
            if (end_byte > self.file_size) {
                end_byte = self.file_size;
            }

            let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
            let response = client
                .get(&self.url)
                .header("Object-Key", self.object_key.to_string())
                .header("Start-Byte", self.start_byte.to_string())
                .header("End-Byte", end_byte.to_string())
                .send();

            match response {
                Ok(_) => {

                    let response_bytes = response.unwrap()
                        .bytes()
                        .map_err(|err| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err))?;

                    // Calculate the number of bytes to copy (minimum between buffer length and remaining bytes)
                    let bytes_to_copy = buf.len().min(response_bytes.len());

                    // Copy the appropriate number of bytes from response_bytes to the buffer
                    buf[..bytes_to_copy].copy_from_slice(&response_bytes[..bytes_to_copy]);

                    self.start_byte += self.chunk_size;

                    Ok(bytes_to_copy)
                }
                Err(err) => Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err)),
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I run the program I've got the following error from the reader.read(&mut read) function.
Err(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: "decryption error" })

I'm expecting that the file chunk downloaded and decrypted before writing in to the file.
How can I fix my program?

One is important every chunk should be go on a separated HTTP request.